# How to lock access to the file directory on the server using XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I'm building an app that takes resources from the server. But how can I lock that resource so that not everyone can access like this picture:
[image]

But when we access along with the file name we can still access it.

[image]

How can I do that? is there a setting on the server? Or whether to make arrangements with the server programming language?
I am very happy if anyone can help my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to change the file permissions.

Comment: how i do to change the file permission @IOGAN ?